# how does graphql in different language perform?

Tags: performance, graphql

GraphQL actually support multiple programming languages; anyone knows which languages has best performance/support for the GraphQL?

Comment: https://github.com/ohler55/graphql-benchmarks

Comment: @DanielRearden I wish I can get more report, especially the common languages; eg Java/Node/Python.